# Gluten-stag! A little cryptic clue for you!

Tags: cryptic-clues

Here is a cryptic clue, can you solve it?

A drink around pledge's entrance- makes walking elevated with a bit of risk. Elementary? Certainly fiction! (15)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Rumplestiltskin

Reasoning

> "A drink" - RUM
>  "around pledge's entrance" - PLE is pledge's entrance and RUM is around (close to) this
>  "makes walking elevated" - STILT
>  "with a bit of risk" - SK (end of risk)
>  "Elementary?" - IN (In is the chemical symbol for the element Indium)
>  "Certainly fiction!" - RUMPLESTILTSKIN is a fictional character

Comment: What is the "gluten stag" reference?  It looks a little like a German greeting - is that it?

Comment: "Guten Tag!" is hello in German. Yet ls is added, in that order.